# How to modify my formula to take 1 hour off?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

E6 = Finish Time.
B6 = Start Time.

My working formula: `=E6-B6+(E6<B6)`   =Time worked in Hours/Minutes

How should I modify my formula to "minus 1 Hour" for a break?

Sounds easy, but I can't get this to work.
Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

- append **`-1/24`** (1 hour for a total of 24 hours per day)

  ```
  =E6-B6+(E6 < B6)-1/24
  ```

  [image: 0]